# Forge upload large files RVT unsuccessful

Tags: web

RVT format model upload forge, the file size of more than 150M upload unsuccessful, can the problem be solved?

Model link http://pan.baidu.com/s/1kVqP2z9

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: More than 150M of the model file in the view submitted project interface directly prompts failed